# How do I download the b1.7.3 server file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want to play b1.7.3 with my friends (it was the first version of Minecraft I ever played!) but I cannot find where/how to download it. I've tried mcversions.net but server files are not included for beta versions.

Comment: Anyone know a download link or something?

Comment: This question is closed, but the other question does not actually contain the beta server link.
Here are some links (be careful):
https://www.mediafire.com/?dnzauup0qg077pr
http://85.219.133.18/Minecraft/BETA/b1.7.3/minecraft_server.b1.7.3.jar

Comment: Sorry if this is spam, i'm just trying to make sure the jar isn't lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN9WeLfdYEg) has the downloads to a variety of old server jars in its description. After downloading the jar and setting up the server, I can confirm that it is functional.

[Here is a direct link to download the b1.7.3 server jar.](https://www.mediafire.com/?dnzauup0qg077pr)